# How normalize case sensitive input using read in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I am a beginner in CLIPS. I need to interact with the user using `read` function. My problem is if the user says *Yes* is different to *YES* and to *yes*.
I was looking a long time in the documentation but I couldn't find any to normalize my input. I try with things like `upper` or `normalize` but don't exist in CLIPS.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the CLIPS 6.4 Basic Programming Guide (http://www.clipsrules.net/Documentation.html) under section 12.3, String Functions. Section 12.3.7, Converting a String to Uppercase, describes the upcase function, and section 12.3.8, Converting a String to Lowercase, describes the lowcase function.

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> (lowcase (read))
Yes
yes
CLIPS> (upcase (read))
no
NO
CLIPS>
```